# Convert string to conditional and statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have string variable like:

```
s = 'apple<3,meizu>5;samsung=9,foo=bar'
```

and a of dictionaries like:

```
 D = [  
        {'apple': 9, 'meizu': 12, 'samsung': 90, 'oppo': 12', foo': 'bar'}, 
        {'apple': 91, 'meizu': 22, 'samsung': 72, 'foo': 'test'},
         ...
     ]
```

I need to convert `s` to

```
"if apple < 3 and (meizu > 5 or samsung==9) and foo=='bar'"  # (semicolon is OR, comma is AND)
```

and check each element of list `D` with this conditional, like:

```
for i in D:
  if i['apple']<3 and (i['meizu']>5 or i['samsung']==9) and i['foo']=='bar':
     print ('ok')
```

I don't understand how to implement it. I tried `eval(s)`, but I'm not sure that is a good solution.

Comment: So, `or` is binding stronger than `and` in this notation? Except for this bit, everything else should be easily doable with simple string replacement.

Comment: Yes, I need convert `semicolon` and `comma` like this example: if you combine OR and AND operators, the OR operator will take precedence

Comment: @tobias_k but in my keys, I am interested in conceptual question, how to convert string to Python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this via a number of string replacements:

- replace `"="` with `"=="` (careful if you also have `<=` and `>=`)
- replace name `x` with `d['x']`; you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback for this
- replace `,` with `and` and `;` with `or`

The tricky part is to make `or` bind stronger than `and`, but you can achieve this by introducing parentheses around all the `and` operators (as well as at the beginning and at the end of the string), but not around the `or`. (This might fail if the string already contains parens, but I'd assume that this is some sort of normalized form without parentheses.)

```
import re
def to_code(string):
    code = "(" + string + ")"
    code = re.sub("[a-z]+", lambda m: "d['%s']" % m.group(0), code)
    code = code.replace(",", ") and (")
    code = code.replace(";", " or ")
    code = code.replace("=", "==")
    return code

s = 'apple<3,meizu>5;samsung=9,foo=bar'
code = to_code(s)
# (d['apple']<3) and (d['meizu']>5 or d['samsung']==9) and (d['foo']==d['bar'])
```

Then, you can `eval` those strings with `d` being the different dictionaries.

```
D = [{'apple': 2, 'meizu': 12, 'samsung': 9, 'oppo': 12, 'foo': 42, 'bar': 42}, 
     {'apple': 91, 'meizu': 22, 'samsung': 72, 'foo': 'test', 'bar': "blub"}]

for d in D:
    print(eval(code)) # prints True, False
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is worked!  About **eval** method - what do you think, how much is a safe solution?  I mean, whether to filter input string should be?

Comment: `eval` always comes with a certain risk, depending on where the string to be evaluated is coming from. In this case, however, I would consider it relatively safe, particularly if all the identifiers are wrapped into `d['...']`, this should prevent most attempt to inject malicious code.